# vlooked up values to new dataframe column 'ADA'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I create a new empty data frame and place my vlooked up values there?

Df1

```
         EW      
0      T1 
1      dwad
```

Df2

```
        AD      FA     
0        T      GN    
1      dwad    dwad
```

Wanting: df(3)

```
    AND    ADA      AVA 
0  NaN     NaN      NaN
1  NaN     dwad     NaN
```

I have:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AND', 'ADA', 'AVA'])
df3

ga = df2.AD=np.where(df2.AD.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)
df2

df3['ADA'] = df2[ga]
```

ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try this

```
df3['ADA']=ga
df3
Out[201]: 
   AND   ADA  AVA
0  NaN   NaN  NaN
1  NaN  dwad  NaN
```